# Imprimir solo una columna concreta de un array bidimensional

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

Quiero imprimir una sola columna, la que yo quiera, de un array bidimensional, he intentado esto:

```
int pos=0;
                 for (int fi=0; fi<bi.length; fi++){
                     System.out.println();
                     for(int col=0; col<bi.length; col++){
                         System.out.print(bi[pos][col]+" ");
                        }
                     }
```

Pero me lo repite cuatro veces, que es la dimensión de mi array.

Comment: Solo pasale el indice de la columna que quieras imprimir `System.out.print(bi[pos][NumeroDeColumnaQueQuierasImprimir]`

Comment: no me entero, tio. Estoy empezando. Si aqui "[NumeroDeColumnaQueQuierasImprimir]" quiero la columna cero, qué pongo?

Comment: Pues ponle 0. y haz la prueba

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo de esta **definiendo la columna e iterando sobre cada fila de tu array**, ejemplo:

```
   int columna = 1; //segunda Columna .

   for(int fila=0;  fila< bi.length; fila++) {
      System.out.println(bi[fila][columna]);
   }
```

Comment: Gracias, pero NO resuelve, lo repite cuatro veces. Sigo igual.

Comment: A que te refieres con que lo repite 4 veces, se supone que solo imprime los valores de la columna , **no debes usar este for:  for (int fi=0; fi<bi.length; fi++){** ya que esto imprimiría 4 veces  @franb70

Comment: que la salida es la columna solicitada, pero repetida cuatro veces, que es la dimensión de mi array [4][4]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
int pos=0;
                 for (int col=0; col<bi.length; col++){
                     System.out.println();
                     System.out.print(bi[col][pos]+" ");
                 }
```

Saludos.

Comment: Que va, eso ya lo intenté y saca la fila, NO la columna, que es lo que interesa.

Comment: invierte `col` por `pos` : algo así:  `System.out.print(bi[pos][col]+" ");`

Comment: mismo problema, lo he intentado todo. la salida es la deseada pero repetida 4 veces La Asignatura y Su Puntuación: 
M01 8 5 10 
M01 8 5 10 
M01 8 5 10 
M01 8 5 10

Comment: Sí lo estas haciendo con 1 solo `for`? porque si mantienes los 2 te lo va a repetir 4 veces.

Comment: no estoy seguro de lo que preguntas, porque soy muy novato, pero el código que estoy usando es System.out.print("La Asignatura y Su Puntuación: ");
     
      int pos=0;
      for (int fi=0; fi<bi.length; fi++){
       System.out.println();
       for(int col=0; col<bi.length; col++){
     
        
        System.out.print(bi[pos][col]+" ");
        
       } 
      }

Comment: es que si solo uso un for, siempre me da la fila, no la columna

Comment: Jodida la solución, eh?

Comment: Ando un poco ocupado por trabajo, veo que ya lo resolviste, básicamente hiciste lo mismo que te puse en mi respuesta. Te recomiendo como ejercicio para que mejores y entres en este mundo del código, analiza tu código y la respuesta que te dí. he intenta descifrar las diferencias y el porqué no te funcionaba. Suerte con tu código! saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, ha sido tu aporte de "un solo for" el que me ha encendido la bombilla. Gracias por el consejo, intentaré seguirlo. Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto!!!

```
int pos=0;

                         for(int col=0; col<bi.length; col++){              

                             System.out.print(bi[0][pos]+" ");  
                             pos++;
                     }
```

Comment: Para las demás columnas, basta con ir aumentando en el print bi[1], bi[2 y dejar siempre pos=0. MUCHAS GRACIAS A TODOS por la ayuda.

Comment: Es lo que **[comentaba aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/335163/95)** de tu pregunta original ,  simplemente no debes usar el primer for: for (int fi=0; fi<bi.length; fi++){ para evitar que imprima 4 veces!